# Is it possible to distribute points based on height?

Tags: modeling, texturing, node-editor, geometry-nodes

Is it possible to distribute points in the geometry nodes based on height like it is with colors in the material nodes?

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

I have this terrain and want points distributed on the blue color. I don't think its possible to have the color as a weight so I thought to just replicate the same node process in the geo nodes

[image: 4]

but that doesn't seem to work either since the density only works if I use an attribute. any suggestions?

this worked:

[image: this worked]

Comment: If you wanna post images, you should just paste them in here. And please post images we can read. And not that low quality that we can’t read anything.

Comment: I didn't know links weren't allowed. But i don't get your issue with the resolution? If you click on the image you can read it just fine. Rhe issue is with this website showing the images in small windows. It is the exact same resolution as i see it in blender. i could have zoomed in on the landscape but the datails of it aren't that important. but on the nodes i dont know how i could have increased the res while still showing everything.

Comment: Now quality is great. Thank you

Comment: Question: why do you think that is is impossible to use the color as weight?

Comment: "Now quality is great. Thank you" i changed nothing lol

but i think i figured something out, i thought it was impossible because i couldn't find anything after like 15 min of searching

Comment: did you try it with "color ramp attribute"?  Attribute -> attribute color ramp ?  and yes, that's why it's called "density **attribute**"

Comment: So i am happy i could help. A "thank you" would have been great. But every person reacts on another way when people helped them. Some "sell" it like they solved it on their own. But maybe then the helping person might not want to help you anymore if you have another question. And commenting with "lol" isn't very respectful either. The quality was totally bad before. Only because you can't see that doesn't mean other people see something different.

Comment: Please don't write *solved* as part of the title. If you found a 
solution for your problem please write it on the 
answers section and mark it as accepted there. Read: 
[what does it mean when an answer is accepted?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 6):

You can use the object space Z coordinate of geometry as an attribute to influence other attributes, if you split it out of the given `position` attribute. Here, it's called `pz`.

[image]

In this case the .5->1 range is soft-mapped to 0->1, and the 1->1.5 range is soft-mapped to 1->0. The results are put into `h_pz` and `l_pz`. When the minimum of those is taken, it's a smooth 0->1->0 distribution, centered on Z=1.That's put into the `d` attribute.

That can be multiplied by some factor, and, in turn, used to control the density of a point distribution.

[image]